# Radial Distribution Function for a Hard Sphere Gas in the Percus-Yevick Approximation - Is There a Quick Way to Evaluate it Numerically?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics

The question is as in the title.

I know that for a one-component hard-sphere gas, there is an analytic solution in the $\vec{k}$-space (PRA, 5, 939). I know that to obtain the correct solution in $r$-space I just need to do something like a Fast Fourier Transform. The problem is that in doing so I can only obtain values for the radial function on a grid, and problem arises as to the magnitude of errors on the grid values, the errors in interpolating between the grid values, and so on.

I have to apologize for the fact that I rarely do fast fourier transforms, and even less estimate their errors.

Is there a standard way (e.g fitting formula) to do this? Thanks.

Comment: I seem to find a reference using density expansion (PRA, 43, 5418; "radial distribution function for hard spheres") for a one-component gas and a reference for a multi-component gas, (Journal of Chemical Physics, 108, 3683; "Structure of multi-component hard-sphere mixtures"). Other better references are much appreciated.

Comment: Indeed there are many references which claimed to give a formula for the evaluation of the radial distribution function for a hard-sphere gas, but many of them contains typos, such that they probably will not give the correct answer. One of them is the ref. given in the previous post (PRA, 43, 5418; "radial distribution function for hard spheres").

Comment: One ref. which seemed to give the correct result is, Molecular Physics, 1975, 30, 1505; "Hard sphere correlation functions in the Percus-Yevick approximation". I would like to stress that the radial distribution function $g(r)$, the total correlation function $h(r)$, as well as the correlation function $c(r)$ are all discontinuous across the hard-sphere diameter $d$, such that a naive (numerical) fourier inversion may or may not work.

Comment: While it is certainly true that $h(r)$ and $c(r)$ are discontinuous across $d$, their difference $h(r)-c(r)$ is not, as can be seen from the Ornstein-Zernike equation. This implies that the Fourier transform of $h(r)-c(r)$ is more well-behaved, and should succumb to a numerical Fourier inversion.